# Angular mat-sidenav open close by Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

As a newbie I am still struggling somewhat with the Angular directives.
How can I open/close mat-sidenav using an observable?

In the scrip of my component I have an observable that gets updated nicely
from other components

```
...
sideNavIsOpen$: Observable<boolean>;
...
```

And this works fine:

```
  <h2 *ngIf="(sideNavIsOpen$ | async)">
      if you see this, value of sideNavIsOpen = true
  </h2>
```

How do I apply the boolean value of the observable to have  open and close.
I tried bunch of things, but not working for me. Something like this would make me happy:

```
 <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" opened="(sideNavIsOpen$ | async)">
 ...
 //  (but this does NOT work):
```

Comment: Where do you get the information from that the sidenav is supposed to be open/closed? Do you perform a backend-call? Or do you use a button?

Comment: From my understanding with angular, if you do not have [] around an attribute it takes the value once then never update. If you add [opened]="..." then it should check the value multiple times and update according.

Answer (score 1):

As **Fyllekanin** described in comments, you need to add square braces around 'opened', like

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" [opened]="(sideNavIsOpen$ | async)">
```